# What makes XLR so durable?

Tags: cable, xlr, connector

According to this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_audio) (2nd alinea), XLR have a durable construction and so are used in combination with a microphone. But what makes a XLR connection so durable? (And why aren't TRS connections not as durable?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XLR connector pros compared to jacks/TRS connectors:

1. It is not as easily pulled out (it locks when connected).
2. It is thicker; thus more rugged
3. The physical interface is larger (pins into tubes), thus better electrical connection.
4. The physical construction makes it much harder to cause disconnection failures due to pulling and pushing.
5. The signal ground is normally not shared with the connectors metal casing (and physically spaced), which preserves floating grounds in equipment where casing is not shared with signal ground.

Comment: Neutrik do make some pretty robust locking jacks, but yes, I agree that they are nowhere near as robust as XLR in general.

Comment: oh... 5. The outer construction & locking device is separate from the electrical components, which are slightly floating within that casing, so any physical strain is not on the electrical connectors themselves.

Comment: Right - added that point - correct?

Comment: Actually, I meant physical separation rather than electrical, but yours is a good point too, possibly better than mine ;)